# Setting IP address of the Guest operating system while launching qemu

Tags: qemu

I am launching qemu using qemu-system-x86_64 along with options. What options should I give to assign IP address for guest OS I launched, so that I can ping the guest os from my host machine.

Can anyone help me on this and post if there any other way to assign IP address of Guest OS other than passing it from command line of qemu-system-x86-64?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good solution to do this via command line.

First and foremost, your best bet is probably [Cloud-Init](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cloud-Init_Support). I've had varying success but I also haven't spent a ton of time perfecting it, either.

You could utilize DHCP and get the IP address from the guest agent after the VM boots. If you are placing it in a network that doesn't have DHCP then you could consider using [dnsmasq on Proxmox](https://computingforgeeks.com/using-dnsmasq-dhcp-server-proxmox-vms/).

If you're using multiple VLANs, you could also consider building the VM in a VLAN with DHCP (either from your router or using the aforementioned Proxmox dnsmasq approach) and then SSH / RDP in and set the static address and move the NIC to the right VLAN.

If you're trying to automate this deployment, I'd recommend using Terraform and Ansible (Terraform to build, Ansible to configure) to accomplish this. I've found the best approach is to configure and trigger the Terraform with Ansible and then save the IPs as facts. You can then use the facts to delegate the Ansible task to the temporary IP and then log in to set the static IP address. If you're changing VLANs then you can either use Terraform or Ansible to adjust the config but I've found Terraform to be best for this task.